# How to align text around a bottom right image using a spacer div (not working in Safari)?

Tags: css, positioning, alignment, vertical-alignment, word-wrap

I have a fixed height div and want to align an image to the bottom right corner with the text (of an unknown/variable length) to wrap around it. I'd ideally like to avoid using Javascript and the best solution so far appears to be to use a vertical spacer div above the image (which is the container height - image height) to push it down. This works perfectly on IE / FF but the text overlaps the top of the image on safari (mobile and standard). I'm not sure why this is happening, I appreciate the fonts are displaying differently but surely the text should flow around the div/image either way? You can see an example of what i'm talking about at http://jsfiddle.net/deshg/XScmK/, i've just used a coloured div with some text instead of an image in this example.

Any thoughts would be massively appreciated as I'm not sure why this isn't working?

Thanks very much as ever,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

in your 3rd div `margin-top:20px;` for a quick fix, but this will push up your 1px wide div.

also try changing these heights: 141px to 140px, and change 159px to 160px.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response, the quick fix isn't really viable as it just adds lots of space to the other browsers however the height changes seem to alleviate the problem but I have no idea why! The intention was to be able to use variable sized images (and the spacer at the top would just be the container height minus image height) but it doesn't appear this will work as it overlaps at certain sizes. Can you explain why it overlaps at certain heights and not others because i cannot for the life of me understand it? Thanks so, so much for your help, Dave

Comment: Dave, it has to do with how each browser interprits line-height. You can try to set your own by using: font: 12px/16px verdana,helvetica,sans-serif; (16px would be the line-height there)

Comment: If you are happy with the answer please vote ans accept it ;)

Comment: Thanks so much for replying but even with specifically definied line heights the overlap still happens in some instances. If you view http://jsfiddle.net/XScmK/35/ (this is the same as the previous code but with your font line added into the wildcard declaration for ease of inserting). If you view this on Safari or Chrome the same problem occurs. I understand evening out the lineheights will make the browser displays more consistent but I still don't see why Safari/Chrome allows the text to run over the top of the image in some instances, surely this should never happen? Thanks so much!

Comment: `font: 12px/14px verdana,helvetica,sans-serif;`

Comment: Hey @paul, i can see that with that exact declaration the text is pushed just above the other div in Safari/Chrome, but only just. The point is that this only works with that exact font size/type and these pixel heights. What i'm trying to establish is why this is happening at all (shouldn't the div stop text from running into it whichever browser you're using), as I need to lay it out based on the design rather than finding font/size combos that happen to display correctly across all browsers if you see what I mean? Thanks so much, Dave

Comment: if i'm correct in assuming that the green box will be transparent and the img will sit inside of it, you can do this: `<div style="float: right; clear: right; height: 152px; padding-top:10px; width: 140px;background-color: #ccdd00;">SAMPLE TEXT IN PLACE OF IMAGE</div>`that removes 10px from the height of the div and adds it back in padding to buffer from webkit's funky behavior of running text over floating divs.

Comment: That still doesn't work in webkit with your original (and some other) font settings unfortunately: http://jsfiddle.net/XScmK/42/ :(